# Connecting to gmail smtp server using c/c++ (sockets)

Tags: c++, email, winsock2

Im tryin' to connect to google smtp server ("smtp.gmail.com") with pure socket.
I created a socket, connect when i read data gives me only "54" or "52" or "53" or "54".

```
    sockaddr_in service;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    struct hostent* remoteHost;

    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (result != NO_ERROR) {
        std::cout << 1;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        WSACleanup;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    remoteHost = gethostbyname(SMTP_HOST);

    memset(&service, 0, sizeof(service));
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_addr.s_addr = *(u_long*)remoteHost->h_addr_list[0];
    service.sin_port = htons(25);


    if (connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        WSACleanup;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char senddata[] = "STARTTLS";

    read_socket();
    send(sock, EHLO, strlen(EHLO), 0);
    read_socket();
    send(sock, senddata, strlen(senddata), 0);

    std::cout << 0;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

My read_socket function

```
void read_socket() {
    int bytesRecv = recv(sock, recvbuf, BUFSIZ, 0);

    if (bytesRecv == 0 || bytesRecv == WSAECONNRESET) {
        std::cout << "Connection closed"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << bytesRecv << std::endl;
}
```

edit: add read_socket function.

Comment: your code seems fine, where is your read_socket funtion code ?

Comment: What are you sending as `EHLO`?

Comment: And `BUFSIZ` is?

Comment: @phoenixstudio edited. I defined EHLO as "EHLO localhost" BUFFSIZ is macro from sdio.h and its int 512

Comment: The 52-54 that you get back - are those outputs of the `std::cout << bytesRecv << std::endl;`? Because the first response line would be about that length, depending on what your public IP address is.

Comment: If the numbers you mention are `bytesRecv`, that's the number of bytes you received in one `recv` call, and it doesn't necessarily receive the entire message.

Comment: @TomoCeferin Yeah its from that line, then how to get output from that smtp server?

Comment: @user13469033 You are not using secure sockets? Since Gmail requires them on both ports 465 and 587.

Comment: Yeah i know that, first i wanted to try connect to smtp server with pure socket. Then i have to use secure sockets but i exactly don't know how.

Comment: I am not able to telnet to the port 25 (used in your example) on Gmail while I am able to do it on 465 and 587. Thus, I doubt you receive anything meaningful. Don't you get an error on connecting?

Comment: In my case now everything working fine
    250-mx.google.com at your service, [1.2.3.4]

Comment: Anyway, the final line of the SMTP response does not contain the dash after the status code. That means that `250-` is the intermediate response, and you should read all the subsequent lines until one like `250 mx.google.com at your service` (no dash here) has been read. Such line is the final response line of your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recv` take as argument the buffer and return the number of bytes recieved, `bytesRecv` in your code is number of bytes recieved (54 bytes) and not the bytes, to find what google answerd you you need to display `recvbuf`

```
std::cout << recvbuf << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the first `recv()` returned only the first line of response.

`250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [1.2.3.4]` (address is different)

You have two choices. Either wait a while before you read so that you get all responses or read in a loop (a better idea) until you have received all responses from SMTP server.